# Atomic emissions and energy time uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Am I right, according the time-energy uncertainty principle, to say that an excited hydrogen atom in free space could emit photons with energies different from those possible by Bohr's calculations?

As you may have noticed, there is no need to mention the fine/hyper-fine corrections and like things.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110657/resonating-frequencies-of-atoms

Comment: What do you mean by *"...time-energy uncertainty principle"*? There is no "the" time-energy uncertainty principle, for time is not an operator and is not one of the configuration space coordinates in Schroedinger equation where non-commuting operators operate. There are more time-energy inequalities with varying meaning. Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The emission lines from hydrogen, and indeed from all atoms, have a finite width i.e. a finite spread of frequencies. As you say, this is an inevitable result of the uncertainty principle.

However this isn't anything terribly exciting. Any wavepacket of a finite duration has a finite uncertainty in wavelength because when you Fourier transform it you get a frequency distribution with a finite width. Since the light emitted from an atom has a finite duration it must have some uncertainty in frequency.

Comment: So can I conclude that there are two sources of uncertainty: 1) Quantum mechanics->This corresponds for the atomic levels themselves. 2) Quantum electrodynamical->This corresponds for photons from the modern perspective.  ?

Comment: *"As you say, this is an inevitable result of the uncertainty principle."* I think it would be better to say *this is inevitable consequence of finite duration of light pulse emitted by an atom.*, for there is no uncertainty in probabilistic sense involved (and no Heisenberg indeterminacy). The relation $\sigma_{E} \sigma_{\tilde{E}} > C$ between standard deviations of field $E(t)$ and its Fourier transform $\tilde{E}(\omega)$ is involved, which is pure mathematics.

Comment: Suppose I prepare hydrogen atoms in the first excited state, and after then, watch them. If you except the uncertainty due the nature of the photons, would expect -ideally- sharp peaks?